# create a jquery function that adds points into total-points column in MySQL table based on comparion

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

jquery comparison of rows from a user prediction table and a result a results table. If the values are identical i want to award 3 point to user and add to total points.

```
$('#pred_table tr').each(function(){

            var currentRowHTML=$(this['Home_Score']&&this['Away_Score']).html();

            $('#fixure tr').each(function(){
                if($(this['Home_Score']&&this['Away_Score']).html()===currentRowHTML){


    //not sure where to begin with the doCalculation function

                    $(this).doCalculation("award 3 points into total points in another
                    table in database");

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Add this to your file:

`<input type="hidden" id="processURL" value="PROCESS.PHP">`

## Put this code:

```
var url = $('#processURL').val();       
  var add_this = 3;     
  var postit = $.post( url, {add_this:add_this});       
  postit.done(function( data ) {
    alert('Three Point Added');    
  });
```

## where this is

```
 //not sure where to begin with the doCalculation function

                    $(this).doCalculation("award 3 points into total points in another
                    table in database");
```

add to the db through `PROCESS.PHP`

If you replace `'Three Point Added'` in the alert with `data` whatever you `echo` on `PROCESS.PHP` will render in the alert.

Comment: NOTE: The answer will process as inquired... not sure if your other code works and not enough info was provided